# Cannot get doctrine 2 many-to-many relationships to work

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities - a User and a Tag.

This is my user:

```
<?php
namespace Project\Model;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="users")
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User", "client" = "Client", "staff" = "Staff"})
 **/
class User implements \JsonSerializable {
  /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
  protected $id;

  /** @Column(type="string", name="first_name") **/
  protected $firstName;

  /**
   * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project\Model\Tag", inversedBy="users")
   * @JoinTable(name="user_tags")
   **/
  protected $tags;

  /**
   * Construct a new user.
   */
  public function __construct() {
    $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
  }

  // Getters

  public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function getFirstName() {
    return $this->firstName;
  }

  public function getTags() {
    return $this->tags;
  }

  // Setters

  public function setFirstName($firstName) {
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
  }

  /**
   * Add a tag to a user.
   * @param Tag
   */
  public function addTag(Tag $tag) {
    $tag->addUser($this);
    $this->tags[] = $tag;
  }
}
```

This is my Tag:

```
<?php
namespace Project\Model;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="tags")
 **/
class Tag implements \JsonSerializable {
  /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
  protected $id;

  /** @Column(type="string") **/
  protected $tag;

  /** 
   *  @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project\Model\User", mappedBy="tags")
   */
  protected $users;

  public function __construct() {
     $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
  }

  // Getters

  public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function getTag() {
    return $this->tag;
  }

  // Setters

  public function setTag($tag) {
    $this->tag = $tag;
  }

  public function addUser(User $user) {
    $this->users[] = $user;
  }
}
```

If I create a new Tag, a new User, add the Tag to the User, then call the getTag() method, it returns nothing -- can anybody help me out where I am going wrong?

```
$tag = new Tag();
$tag->setTag('Foo');
$entityManager->persist($tag);

$user = new User();
$user->addTag($tag);
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManger->flush();

var_dump($user->getTags());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might come from your ManyToMany relation. You use

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="users")
```

whereas you should have something like (assuming you are using Symfony 2 of course) :

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Tag")
```

Also, you use a `inversedBy`but no `mappedBy`, so your mapping is invalid.

And this last one is more of a detail, but name a property "tag" inside a Tag class is not the cleanest. Maybe change it to "name".

Comment: I've updated my question to include my namespacing. Also I'm not using Symfony. Where should I have the mappedBy?

Comment: Either you delete your "inverdedBy" mapping and you have a unidirectional relation between your entities, or you add to your Tag entity a $users property with the annotation : `@ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project\Model\User", inversedBy="tags")` 
and then it becomes bidirectional.

Comment: I with the second option, however it still didn't work. Also according to doctrine documentation the Tag entity annotation should be mappedBy, not inversedBy. I tried that and it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your Tag class, you reference the User class using:

```
/** 
 *  @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bix\Model\User", mappedBy="tags")
 */
```

Should "Bix" be "Project"? Unless this was a typo in your question, that woud cause issues.

One side should "own" the association and be responsible for setting the inverse association when it is added.

```
<?php

// Assuming that the User is the "owning side".

class User {

    // Mappings as you have them, minus the "Bix" namespace thing.

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        $tag->addUser($this);
        $this->tags->add($tag);
    }

    public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        $tag->removeUser($this);
        $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
    }
}

class Tag {

    // Mappings as you have them, minus the "Bix" namespace thing.

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->users->add($user);
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }
}
```